# Retrieving a jpeg image over Facebook loses quality drastically.

Tags: php, facebook, image, image-processing, facebook-php-sdk

I've been struggling to an issue of saving an image into jpeg which loses quality. As a project for my degree, I'm making an app where i upload the images on facebook.

I have a nice colored image, for which i shuffle the pixel values to get a mapped image. Then I upload it onto the facebook. When, i download and move the pixels back to original image, it loses the quality too much.

Below  are the original, mapped and retrieved images:

[image: original] 
[image: masked]
[image: retrived image]

I've tried many strategies like using png files, which works. But, currently, whatever the image is, facebook converts it to jpeg. So, if i upload maskedimage.png to facebook, it converts it to .jpg and loses some of the pixel-correlation values, which doesnt end up giving me the right image to retrieve original.

I'm using PHP and facebook-php sdk.

Please suggest.
Thank you
-Kaur

Answer (score 3):

You're stuck. JPEG is a lossy algorithm which depends on human vision characteristics to mask the inaccuracies. By scrambling the pixels you've changed the nature of the loss so that it's not invisible anymore.

Comment: oh! Isn't there any alternative? can i put some kind of filters on the retrieved image to make it colored in php?

Comment: @kaur, you can't put back what has been removed. The information just doesn't exist anymore. Your only choice is to use a format other than JPEG, and if that option isn't available there's little you can do.

Comment: @kaur: the problem is not with JPEG being lossy, but with Facebook forcing recompression. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13600708/1269037) for more details.

Comment: @DanDascalescu, that doesn't make my answer any less true.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't primarily about JPEG being lossy; it's about Facebook forcing image recompression, even if you check "High quality" when uploading.

The best you can do is to double the source image resolution, and for solid colors, try to introduce noise. Details in this [GD.SE question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/facebook-ways-to-preserve-image-quality-of-uploaded-images)

Note that the trick of uploading images <100kb has no longer been working, since at least [June 2012](http://www.vancouverpov.ca/wp/social-media/tips-to-improve-facebook-cover-photo-quality/#comment-5483).